# How do I manually install llvm-profdata tool?

Tags: llvm

> I have installed llvm-3.4 & clang-3.4 in debug+asserts mode.
>  It does not have the *llvm-prof* data tool.
>  
>   Can I install it separately, if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

The `llvm-profdata` tool was added to the tree in February 2014 ([r201535](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=201535)), which is well after the 3.4 release branched ([r195082](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=195082)).

You should probably try a more recent release as well -- a *lot* has changed in LLVM since 3.4, especially with respect to PGO. In fact, PGO is one of the most actively developed aspects of LLVM so if you can, I would even encourage you to try checking out LLVM and Clang from source and tracking the top-of-tree. While sometimes a bad commit lands, we try to quickly revert back to green and keep the top of tree continuously in a healthy state.

Comment: In order to stay up to date, a major hurdle I've found is that you have to understand how svn works. Even though it is by all accounts I've heard, obsoleted by git. Since there is a git mirror updated every 5 minutes, and you will no doubt eventually remove the extra hurdle, I'd appreciate a comment linking to "how to migrate your llvm svn repository to track the git repository/mirror".